# what is the linux command to check ram usage for a service?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu OS. When I do `service --status-all` then it lists all services running.

[image]

I would like to find RAM usage of the marked tomcat instances. How can I do so? Thanks!

Comment: [top](https://www.tecmint.com/12-top-command-examples-in-linux/) command may help.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

run command `top` in your terminal you can see the PID and process-name and ram-usage and lots of more stuff

Comment: Please avoid answering [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) fodder. Instead, close it and move on. It is sometimes helpful to suggest a site where the question may be on-topic.